# Show modal when a user selects value in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript

I would like a modal to popup when a user selects a given option in a dropdown menu.

This is what i have tried:

```
<a class="justify-content-between d-flex">
                            <p>Installments</p>
                            <div>
                                <select class="installments-selector" onchange="changeInstallments()">
                                    <option>Two Months</option>
                                    <!-- two months modal -->
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="TwoMonthsModal" role="dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                                                        Payment over two months
                                                    </h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    In test2.
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <option>Three Months</option>
                                    <!-- three months modal -->
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="ThreeMonthsModal" role="dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                                                        Payment over two months
                                                    </h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    In test.
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            </a>
```

here is the javascript

```
<script>
    function changeInstallments()
    {
    function(e){
    var installments = $('.installments-selector').val();
    if (installments == 'Two Months') {
    $('#TwoMonthsModal').modal('show');}
    else if (installments == 'Three Months') {
    $('#ThreeMonthsModal').modal('show);}
    }
</script>
```

I tried adapting a solution I found but to no avail. This is what I tried

javascript:

```
<script>
$("installments-selector").on('change', function() {
if ($this).val() == 1) {
    $("#TwoMonthsModal").modal('show');}
else if($this).val() == 2) {
    $("#ThreeMonthsModal").modal('show');}
});
</script>
```

html

```
<select id="installments-selector">
   <option value="1">Two Months</option>
   <option value="2">Three Months</option>
</select>
```

However, I am still not getting a popup modal when I select any of the options in my dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you, set the value on modal on value or data-attribute on options, after get the value and used for launch modal.

Here an little example:

References to JQuery and bootstrap are missing, but I hope it's a guide to the idea

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a class="justify-content-between d-flex">
        <p>Installments</p>
        <div>
            <select class="installments-selector" onchange="changeInstallments()">
                <option value="TwoMonthsModal">Two Months</option>
                <option value="ThreeMonthsModal">Three Months</option>
            </select>
            <div class="modal fade" id="TwoMonthsModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">
                                Payment over two months
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            In the statistics part of the curriculum you will cover topics such as rules of probability,
                            different types of probability distributions and inferential statistics to name a few.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- three months modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="ThreeMonthsModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">
                                Payment over two months
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            In the statistics part of the curriculum you will cover topics such as rules of probability,
                            different types of probability distributions and inferential statistics to name a few.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <script>
        function changeInstallments() {
            var installments = $('.installments-selector').val();
            $(document.getElementById(installments)).modal('show');
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this might be similar to the attempted solution I just added to my question?

Comment: Yes, I only adapted your code, and apart modal code the option select.